# JSON + Java Character Decoding

Tags: java, json, encoding

My code below is using Java's URLConnection to ping a RESTful API which will return a JSON string.  The JSON string that I get back appears to be completely valid, but fails in both JSONLint and the final line of code below.

The returned JSON is:

> { "rowId": "1-12C-1494" }

The error message is:

> Parse error on line 2:
>   ...rowId": "1-12C-1494"
>   -----------------------^
>   Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'

The code is:

```
StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream cin = connection.getInputStream();
int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while ((bytesRead = cin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    responseBuilder.append(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
}

String response = responseBuilder.toString();

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();
```

If I ping the RESTful API from a browser and copy the JSON there into JSONLint it validates just fine.  The best I can tell this some kind of character/whitespace encoding issue.  Has anyone else run into it and have any guidance?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it had to do with how I was going from Stream to String.  The method in the example above left a ~1000 byte gap in the middle of JSON.  JSONLint treated it as a whitespace character it couldn't interpret or even render.

Moral of the story... don't use the method I did to go from InputStream to String.  This works much better:

```
InputStream cin = connection.getInputStream();

java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(cin).useDelimiter("\\A");
(StringBuilder)responseBuilder.append(s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "");
```

See [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) for discussion